# not a reading user inputs

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that asks for an input of 1, 2, or q. 1 will ask for an input, will print the input, and then print the adjusted input. 2 will do the exact opposite of 1, asking for an input and then printing the decoded version. q will quit the program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class StringyString {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str;
        //int n;
        boolean whatever  = true;

        while(whatever){
                System.out.println("If you would like to type something w/o using the formula, type 1");
                System.out.println("If you would like to type something using the formula, type 2");
                System.out.println("If you would like to quit, type q");

                str = br.readLine();


                if(str == "1"){
                    System.out.println("Type something below and press enter to end your input");
                    String str1 = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Your word is " + str1);
                    System.out.println("Your altered word is: ");

                    String str2 = str1.replace('A', 'Q');
                    String str3 = str2.replace('E', 'W');
                    String str4 = str3.replace('I', 'L');
                    String str5 = str4.replace('O', 'P');
                    String str6 = str5.replace('U', 'G');
                    String str7 = str6.replace('1', 'J');
            //str = s7r.replace(‘J uuuuu’, ‘1’);
                    String str8 = str7.replace('5', 'S');
                    String str9 = str8.replace('S', '5');
                    String str10 = str9.replace('8', 'B');
                    String str11 = str10.replace('B', '8');

                    System.out.println(str11);

                }
                if(str == "2"){
                    System.out.println("Type something below and type '/.' to end your input");
                    str = br.readLine();
            //n = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    System.out.println("Your word is " + str);
                    System.out.println("Your decoded word is: ");

                    str = str.replace('Q', 'A');
                    str = str.replace('W', 'E');
                    str = str.replace('L', 'I');
                    str = str.replace('P', 'O');
                    str = str.replace('G', 'U');
                    str = str.replace('1', 'J');
                    str = str.replace('J', '1');
                    str = str.replace('5', 'S');
                    str = str.replace('S', '5');
                    str = str.replace('8', 'B');
                    str = str.replace('B', '8');

                    System.out.println(str);

        }
                while(str != "q"){
                    whatever = true;

                }
               // System.out.println(str);

                }
    }
}
```

However, every time i run the program, it doesn't except my input. 
Output:
If you would like to type something w/o using the formula, type 1
If you would like to type something with the formula, type 2
If you would like to quit, type q
[input]
[nothing happens but you can keep putting in inputs]

Can anyone solve this for me??? TIA and sorry if this is the wrong way to format the code

Comment: Your problem appears to be you are in `while(whatever)`, and you never set `whatever` to `false`.  Change `while(str != "q"){whatever = true;}` to `if(str == "q"){whatever = false;}`.  The reason you can keep inputting values is because you go into a second, infinite, `while` loop here.

Comment: Also comparing string with `==` in java isn't right. use `if (str.equals("1"))`

Comment: `while(str != "q"){` nope. yet again another `String` comparison issue question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very long and bad ......but you can try this ,i have done minimum changes....

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str;
    //int n;
    boolean whatever  = true;

    while(whatever){
            System.out.println("If you would like to type something w/o using the formula, type 1");
            System.out.println("If you would like to type something using the formula, type 2");
            System.out.println("If you would like to quit, type 0");

            str = br.readLine();


            if(Integer.parseInt(str)==1){
                System.out.println("Type something below and press enter to end your input");
                String str1 = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Your word is " + str1);
                System.out.println("Your altered word is: ");

              str1 = str1.replace('A', 'Q');
                str1 = str1.replace('E', 'W');
                 str1 = str1.replace('I', 'L');
                 str1 = str1.replace('O', 'P');
                str1 = str1.replace('U', 'G');
                str1 = str1.replace('1', 'J');
        //str = s7r.replace(‘J uuuuu’, ‘1’);
                 str1 = str1.replace('5', 'S');
                 str1 = str1.replace('S', '5');
                str1 = str1.replace('8', 'B');
                str1 = str1.replace('B', '8');

                System.out.println(str1);

            }

            else if(Integer.parseInt(str)==2){
                System.out.println("Type something below and type '/.' to end your input");
                str = br.readLine();

                System.out.println("Your word is " + str);
                System.out.println("Your decoded word is: ");

                str= str.replace('Q', 'A');
                 str= str.replace('W', 'E');
                 str= str.replace('L', 'I');
                 str= str.replace('P', 'O');
                 str= str.replace('G', 'U');
                 str= str.replace('1', 'J');
                 str= str.replace('J', '1');
                 str= str.replace('5', 'S');
                 str= str.replace('S', '5');
                 str= str.replace('8', 'B');
                 str= str.replace('B', '8');

                System.out.println(str);
                }
            else if(Integer.parseInt(str)==0){
            System.out.println("Quit");
             whatever = true;
             break;
             }
             else{
             System.out.println("Wrong Input Try Again!");
             }


    }



  }          
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, this was really helpful. I'm still working on my coding skills but y'alls responses got me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jacob.I am always here for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this section right here:

```
while(str != "q")
{
    whatever = true;
}
```

Here, you have entered an infinite loop, and the system is not reading in any values from you - just looping forever.  An additional problem is that even if `str` was "q", you never set `str` to `false` to break the `while(whatever)` loop.  Try using this code instead:

```
if(str.equals("q"))
{
    whatever = false;
}
```

As John3136 noted, you shouldn't use the `==` operator to compare strings in Java, you should use `str.equals(value)` instead.

For further changes, please do not name variables `whatever`; the name doesn't tell you what the variable is doing, which will make it much more difficult to debug your program.